# Merge does not update in JPA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_period")
public class Period {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "periodSeq")
    @Column(name = "PERIOD_ID", unique = true, nullable = true)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "periodSeq", sequenceName = "seq_period", allocationSize=1)
    private Long periodId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    ClassGroup classGroup;

    @Column(name="PERIOD1")
    Integer period1;

    @Column(name="PERIOD2")
    Integer period2;

    ...
}
```

and..

```
/**
 * ProductGroup generated by Tomasz Borowiec
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CLASS_GROUP", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "KEY"))
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqCLASS_GROUP", sequenceName = "SEQ_CLASS_GROUP")
public class ClassGroup implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String key;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqCLASS_GROUP")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

...

}
```

the DAO

```
public class PeriodDaoImpl extends JpaDaoSupport implements PeriodDao {
       ...
    @Override
    public Period saveOrUpdate(Period period) throws Exception {

        if (period.getPeriodId() == null &&
                find(period.getClassGroup()) == null) {
            getEntityManager().persist(period);

        } else {

            period = getEntityManager().merge(period);
        }

        return period;
    }
        ...
}
```

and this code in the Junit to test the DAO:

```
    ClassGroup classGroup = classGroupDao.findById(1);

    Period period = new Period();
    period.setClassGroup(classGroup)
    period.setPeriod1(1);

    period = periodDao.saveOrUpdate(period);
    period.setPeriod1(2);
    period = periodDao.saveOrUpdate(period);
```

I got this error in the second update, executing the merge, not persist

In the DataBase level I set a unique Key for the object classGroup:

```
CREATE TABLE t_period
(
  period_id number(38) not null,
  class_group_id number(38) not null,
  period1 number,
  period2 number,
  CONSTRAINT pk_period PRIMARY KEY        (period_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_class_group   FOREIGN KEY (class_group_id) REFERENCES t_class_group(id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_class_group UNIQUE        (class_group_id)
);
```

ORA-00001: unique constraint (ENV_ECAT.UK_CLASS_GROUP) violated

Comment: it would be good if you can show your complete exception stack trace

Comment: primary key is periodId (that is generated automatically by a sequence) , not period1

Comment: Whole stacktrace and what constraint you have violated would be helpfull. ClassGroup mapping might also be nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code, `persist` is never executed because `find(period.getClassGroup())` will never return null. That means `merge()` is called twice, but it doesn't give you the id back so I think that's why it's trying to insert the same object twice.

So, try removing `find(...)` from `if` statement to see if it works.

```
if (period.getPeriodId() == null) {
    getEntityManager().persist(period);
}
```

If it does work, you'll have to come up with different condition to branch calls to `merge()` and `persist()`.